# how to keep the visible content after nstableview reloaddata?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I have a subclassed nstableview whose data source array may increase, by calling reloadData: I can refresh to reflect the data updating.

But after reloadData:, the tableview will always scroll to the new cell with the same old row number (for example, if the tableview was showing the 2nd cell, after reloadData:, the tableview will scroll to the new 2nd cell, therefore, the visible content of the tableview will change). How can I disable this automatic behavior and keep the visible content unchanged after the updating?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this problem fixed: first, I got the rect size changed amount; then after the reloadData: , scroll the tableview to the changed point (original point + delta parts) immediately with the clipview's scrollToPoint: method. It does it so fast that you cannot realize the operation there.

Comment: I have implemented this, but i am getting a bit of jitter, is your scrolling smooth ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925136/nstableview-scrollrowtovisible-with-animation

Answer (score 1):

Table views don't re-scroll when their content changes. Since you're changing the table content which underlies the currently displayed rows, you need to move the scroll yourself.

I don't have code for this, but I suggest using `rowAtPoint:` to find the initial position of the table view, identifying or calculating the new row index for that row's content, and then calling:

```
[tableView reloadData];
[tableView scrollRowToVisible:newIndex];
```

Comment: Thanks, noa, your answer really gave me inspirations!