# making insertRowAtIndexes:withAnimation visible when inserting new row at end

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I'm using insertRowAtIndexes:withAnimation to add a new row to an NSTableView.

If the rect of the new row is already visible then this works fine but there is a problem when inserting a new row at the end. The row gets inserted as expected but since the scroll position doesn't adjust, the animation happens offscreen!

Any obvious fix I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the new row visible manually. You can't call `-rectOfRow:` on the row you are inserting, because it's not in the table yet -- instead, look at the rect of the last row in the table, add the expected height of the new row, and then see if the resulting rect will be visible onscreen; if not, you need to scroll.

See [NSTableView scrollRowToVisible with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925136/nstableview-scrollrowtovisible-with-animation) if you want to animate the scroll. Note that on 10.7+ you probably want to call [`-flashScrollers`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScrollView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScrollView/flashScrollers) on the scrollview as well.

Comment: Thanks. I'm already checking to see if the to be removed/inserted row is visible and scrolling first if necessary. So inserting at the bottom is a special case and I'll have to handle it differently, with a (no-animation) insert followed by animated scroll to the bottom. I'm sure visually this will look as if the inserted row is animating in.