# Adding row to NSTableView doesn't change its frame

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsscrollview

I'm trying to insert a new row at the end of a `NSTableView`, scroll to it and start editing it. Everything seems to work fine except for the scrolling. The table view seems to scroll to the row immediately before the last (which is the row I have just added).

Here is the code I use:

```
- (void)insertNewRowInMainTable
{
    [self logScrollView];

    NSUInteger lastRow = self.mainTableView.numberOfRows;
    [self.mainTableView insertRowsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:lastRow] withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationEffectFade];
    [self.mainTableView editColumn:0 row:lastRow withEvent:nil select:YES];

    NSLog(@"Inserted Row");
    NSLog(@"last row rect: %@",NSStringFromRect([self.mainTableView rectOfRow:lastRow]));
    [self logScrollView];
}

- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSInteger selectedRow = [self.mainTableView selectedRow];
    [self.mainTableView scrollRowToVisible:selectedRow];
}

- (void)logScrollView
{
    NSScrollView *scrollView = [self.mainTableView enclosingScrollView];
    NSLog(@"Document visible rect: %@",NSStringFromRect([scrollView documentVisibleRect]));
    NSLog(@"Table view frame: %@",NSStringFromRect([self.mainTableView frame]));

    NSInteger selectedRow = [self.mainTableView selectedRow];
    NSLog(@"Selected row rect: %@",NSStringFromRect([self.mainTableView rectOfRow:selectedRow]));
}
```

And here is the output of the logs:

```
2013-05-01 16:22:04.254 DEGS[96570:303] Document visible rect: {{0, 0}, {509, 506}}
2013-05-01 16:22:04.255 DEGS[96570:303] Table view frame: {{0, -204}, {509, 1732}}
2013-05-01 16:22:04.256 DEGS[96570:303] Selected row rect: {{0, 0}, {509, 209}}
2013-05-01 16:22:04.287 DEGS[96570:303] Inserted Row
2013-05-01 16:22:04.287 DEGS[96570:303] last row rect: {{0, 1732}, {509, 161}}
2013-05-01 16:22:04.288 DEGS[96570:303] Document visible rect: {{0, 1226}, {509, 506}}
2013-05-01 16:22:04.288 DEGS[96570:303] Table view frame: {{0, -204}, {509, 1732}}
2013-05-01 16:22:04.288 DEGS[96570:303] Selected row rect: {{0, 1732}, {509, 161}}
```

I can see from the log that inserting the new row does not change the table view frame size. Hence when I do the scrolling to the last row, the scroll view scrolls to the bottom of the contentView but with the wrong size showing only the second last row.

I can probably fix this by manually moving the scroll view after I insert the row but I would like to understand if it's a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1):

Inserting a new row does not scroll the table view. This is the given feature.

You need to scroll down to see the last added row.

This method does that for  you:

```
- (void)scrollRowToVisible:(NSInteger)row;
```

Comment: Yeah but in my code I call the `-editColumn:row:withEvent:select:` method of the table view with YES for select. This then invokes the `-tableViewSelectionDidChange:` delegate method that does the scrolling to the selected cell. As I said the scrolling happens when I insert a new cell but it scrolls to the wrong position. It scroll to the second last cell instead of the last.

Comment: selDidChange doesn't scroll to last row.

Comment: Yeah but if you look at my code above you'll see that I call `-scrollRowToVisible:` to the selected row in selDidChange

Comment: try using  `NSInteger selectedRow = [self.mainTableView selectedRow];
    [self.mainTableView scrollRowToVisible:selectedRow];` just after adding new row.

Comment: Still no luck! As I said the problem seems to be that the table view does not adjust the height of its frame after I insert the new row hence when the scrolling happen the scroll view computes the wrong position.

Comment: I've noticed this also. The TableViewPlayground sample can be modified to scroll to the last row and the same behavior is seen (scrolling to first row, as the sample is configured by default, works fine) - update: actually, when I remove the begin/endUpdates calls for the view-based table it works as expected when scrolling to the last row.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, newly added row would not be scrolled to, or just one pixel or two from the top would be displayed depending on table scroll position. I implemented [manual scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8480325/172690) and now it works very good.