# How to scrollRowToVisible without animations

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

On a Mac, Mail and Finder have a solid looking scroll on their table views when the up or down arrow is held. The row highlight sits flush with the top or bottom of the column and the rows step through with no animation.

8 years ago it seems that it was [hard to not do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925136). Now I can't seem to stop `scrollRowToVisible` on an `NSOutlineView` animating.

I have tried wrapping the call with `NSAnimationContext.beginGrouping()` or `CATransaction.begin()` etc to set any animation duration to `0.0` but no luck.

Is there anyway to make this call snap - or should I be using something a little lower level?

EDIT

Here is my code. The duration has no effect here. There are always a few frames of scroll animation, and the endpoint of the animation is slightly irregular (i.e. the bottom edge of the scrolled to view is not always aligned with the bottom edge).

```
if selectedRows != outlineView.selectedRowIndexes {
            outlineView.selectRowIndexes(selectedRows, byExtendingSelection: false)

            // I would love this not to animate like in mail, but it cannot be stopped!!!
            if selectedRows.one {
                NSAnimationContext.beginGrouping()
                NSAnimationContext.current.allowsImplicitAnimation = false
                NSAnimationContext.current.duration = 0
                outlineView.scrollRowToVisible(selectedRows.first!)
                NSAnimationContext.endGrouping()
            }
        }
```

Using runAnimationGroup has the same result:

```
NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup( { current in
                    current.allowsImplicitAnimation = false
                    current.duration = 0
                    outlineView.scrollRowToVisible(selectedRows.first!)
                }, completionHandler: nil)
```

I have variable height rows in my table but I don't see why this would make a difference. From the above code, the change in selection is always highlighted before any movement in the table, further indication that the scroll animation is not being removed.

Comment: Did you try the [4 your old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32104389/4244136) to the linked question? Do `context.allowsImplicitAnimation = NO;`.

Comment: Thank you @Willeke, I have tried using `allowsImplicitAnimation = false` within `NSAnimationContext.beginGrouping`, with a zero duration too, but I still see the same animation.

Comment: The answer works for me. Post your code please.

Comment: @Willeke, code posted. Thanks.

Comment: @Willeke, yes, the runAnimationGroup block similarly has no effect. Scroll, Clip and Outline views all have wantsLayer set to true.

Comment: Weird, now my outline view doesn't animate unless I tell it to. It could be a setting somewhere. Did you insert rows just before `scrollRowToVisible`?

Comment: No, i just set the row selection, then scroll to it. No insertion, expansion etc.

Comment: `scrollRowToVisible` does `rect(ofRow:)` and `scrollToVisible(_:)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem myself, and solved it by subclassing `NSClipView` and overriding `func scroll(to newOrigin: NSPoint)` like this:

```
override func scroll(to newOrigin: NSPoint) {
    super.setBoundsOrigin(newOrigin)
}
```

This should disable smooth scroll entirely, which is the animation effect you are describing, for the scroll view that houses your subclassed clip view.

Comment: Perfect. Great first contribution! Thank you.